# Come back to the line at the end of a cell in a csv file with php

Tags: php, csv

I would like to return to the line in my csv file, automatically if is end of cell of the csv file, not in the end of data.

I don't want to use fputcsv function ...

```
$csv = utf8_decode('Export csv 

        Extrait du SIR Web - le '.date('d/m/Y').'
        Pour l\'année : '.$annee.'
        Auditeur : '.$auditeur.'
        Zone audit : '.$zoneaudit.'
        Dpt : '.$departement.'

        ');
        $csv .= utf8_decode('Code centre;Agrément;Auditeur;Zone audit;Date audit;Numéro NC;Code NC;Délai AC;Délai Rép;Validée;Date Validation;Info val au centre;Date rel 1;Date rel 2;Dernier délai;Observations;Date codir;Sanction codir;Clôture d\'Audit;Observations;Action corrective');

        foreach ($aResultStats as $row){

            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_a']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_b']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_c']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_d']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_e']).';';
            $csv .= '="'.utf8_decode($row['data_f']).'";';
            $csv .= utf8_decode(trim($row['data_g'])).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_h']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_i']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_j']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_k']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_l']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_m']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_n']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_o']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_p']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_q']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_r']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode($row['data_s']).';';
            $csv .= utf8_decode(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),' ',$row['data_t'])).';
';
            /*$csv .= utf8_decode(str_replace(array("\\r\", "\", "\\r"),array(" ", " ", " "),$row['data_t'])).';';*/
            $csv .= utf8_decode(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),' ',$row['data_u'])).' 
';

    }

      $filename = 'export_' . date('Ymd') .'_' . date('His');
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv");

        echo $csv;
```

In this picture, T and U are two columns, the data of the T columns overflows on the U columns and more...

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: "I don't want to use fputcsv function"...why not? Is there a problem with it? It ought to make things a lot easier. But anyway, it's not actually relevant to this. The overflow you're seeing is just a feature of the display in Excel, nothing to do with the CSV format. Open it in a text editor (Notepad++ is good for this kind of thing) to see the actual raw output. CSV does not store any information regarding things like column overflow - it has no concept of the visual presentation of the data. You can set this option in Excel each time you open it, but it will not be saved with the CSV file.

Comment: The data overflow is just how your application (Excel?) deals with text that is larger than the visible column width.

Comment: Also you are setting the content-type header incorrectly - this is not an Excel file. There is a separate MIME Type for csv (`text/csv`)

Comment: @ADyson 
Thank you for your answer
I do not use the fputcsv function
because I correct this quickly, without redoing the code ...

Comment: OK so there is nothing to add in the code to prevent it from overflowing ? 
and with the function "fputcsv" how can I avoid that @ADyson ?

Comment: Like I said, this is because the file format does not store any display-related information. How you _create_ that file is irrelevant, the format is the same. Using fputcsv won't resolve that. Mentioning fputcsv was just an aside about your code in general. If you really really need to set the overflow display attribute, you'd have to create an actual Excel (.xlsx) file instead of using CSV - there are PHP libraries which can help with that.

Comment: OK thanks again for your return @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson, actually yes. `fputcsv` and `fgetcsv` have a lot of issues, they are poorly written in PHP, especially the escaping and quotation parts. Moreover, each language and software (like Excel, Numbers, etc) have each a different version of implementation and standards (very sad situation). I know this is not related to the OP question, but FYI.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a break line character in the middle of the row content, right after the last delimiter. This may cause an unexpected behavior.

   ```
           $csv .= utf8_decode(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),' ',$row['data_t'])).';
   ';
   ```

   It should be something like this

   ```
   $csv .= utf8_decode(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),' ',$row['data_t'])).';';
   ```
2. It is always better in CSV to wrap in quotations when handling UGC, rather than relying on special characters removal.

   ```
   $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', utf8_decode($row['data_t']) . '";';
   $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', utf8_decode($row['data_u']) . "\"\n";
   ```
3. You have set an incorrect Content-Type for CSV file. It should be `text/csv` or you can just leave it as `text/plain`.

Comment: thanks @Slavik Meltser for your answer, i change the break line ...  and the next solution didn't work...